# How to make Django API with registration and login

Tags: django, api

I am trying to make an API in Django that returns employee info as JSON only when a user is logged in.

My question is, how can I make a user registration and log in option without the use of html and forms?
Is there a way for me to create a registration option that takes in input sent by a client via JSON. For example, a POST request to localhost:example/register/ which contained :

`{"username" : "examle", "email" : "example", "password" : "example", "password2" : "example"}?`

How would this be implemented in views.py?

Any help would be appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: You can use Django Rest framework to build an API.

Comment: I know how to create the API. What I don't understand is how to make a Register and Log In option for the API. I have edited the above question in case this wasn't clear. Thank you for the tip regardless.

Comment: As I said you need Django Rest framework for that. You can make special url for registration that accepts only `post` requests and then create new user in the view based on a data from the request.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is a way, and Django Rest Framework includes almost everything you need.

To answer your first question about being logged in, you would add a permissions class to only allow access to someone who is authenticated.

To answer your API question for registration, you'll want to create an API endpoint in whichever URL file is relevant; I put my in my Users app:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('register/', register_user_view, name="register"),
...
]
```

You'll want to create a view and serializer to ingest the JSON you're sending in:

```
@api_view(['POST',])
def register_user_view(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        serializer = RegistrationSerializer(data=request.data)
        data = {}
        if serializer.is_valid():
            account = serializer.save()
            data['response'] = "successfully registered a new user."
            data['email'] = account.email
            data['response'] = account.username
        else:
            data = serializer.errors
            # data = serializer.data
        return Response(data)
```

Serializer:

```
class RegistrationSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    password2 = serializers.CharField(style={'input_type': 'password'}, write_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = CustomUser
        fields = ['email', 'username', 'password', 'password2']
        extra_kwargs = {
            'password': {'write_only': True}
        }

    def save(self):
        account = CustomUser(
            email=self.validated_data['email'],
            username=self.validated_data['username'],
        )
        password = self.validated_data['password']
        password2 = self.validated_data['password2']

        if password != password2:
            raise serializers.ValidationError({'password': 'Passwords do not match!'})

        account.set_password(password)
        account.save()
        return account
```

Comment: Is it right to assume that you have made a Model in the models.py file that stores the data posted. Also why is there two data['response']'s in the second example?